# Bubble graphs - how to use?

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to combinate "normal points" and "bubble points"? I have two sets of data - file1.txt and file2.txt and for one of them (file2.txt) I would like to use points like http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/06/

How to compose this into code please? When I use the code from that webpage how to plot another data. I tried this:

```
f(x) = A*exp(-x*x/B/B)
rx=0.107071; ry=0.057876; A = 1; B = 0.2; C=0.5*rx; D=-0.4*ry
g(u,v) = (2*cos(u)*v*rx+C)*(2*cos(u)*v*rx+C)+(3.5*sin(u)*v*ry+D)*(3.5*sin(u)*v*ry+D)             
unset key; unset colorbox; set view map
set xrange [-0.15:5.2]; set yrange [-0.7:0.95]
set parametric; set urange [0:2*pi]; set vrange [0:1]                         
set isosamples 20, 20; set samples 30                                         
set palette model HSV functions 1, 1-f(gray), 1+2*f(gray)                     
splot cos(u)*rx*v-0.13335347,sin(u)*ry*v+2.7730389, g(u,v) w pm3d, \
cos(u)*rx*v-0.11625481,sin(u)*ry*v+3.5312312, g(u,v) w pm3d, \
cos(u)*rx*v-0.14454222,sin(u)*ry*v+3.6412394, g(u,v) w pm3d, \
cos(u)*rx*v-0.070272446,sin(u)*ry*v+3.8070912, g(u,v) w pm3d, \
cos(u)*rx*v-0.10077238,sin(u)*ry*v+4.090774, g(u,v) w pm3d, \
'file1.txt' using 2:1:(0.0):2 with points pt 7 ps 1 palette
```

but file2 is not splot. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a variant of the "trick" shown in your [second link](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/09/bubble-graphs-in-gnuplot-once-more.html). I have extracted the customized point styles into a pre-defined set of linetypes. This makes the plot command itself simpler, and it is easier to reuse the definitions in multiple plots.

```
set linetype 101   ps 3.0 pt 7 lc rgb "#ff0000"
set linetype 102   ps 2.6 pt 7 lc rgb "#ff2222"
set linetype 103   ps 2.2 pt 7 lc rgb "#ff4444"
set linetype 104   ps 1.8 pt 7 lc rgb "#ff6666"
set linetype 105   ps 1.4 pt 7 lc rgb "#ff8888"
set linetype 106   ps 1.0 pt 7 lc rgb "#ffaaaa"
set linetype 107   ps 0.6 pt 7 lc rgb "#ffcccc"
set linetype 108   ps 0.2 pt 7 lc rgb "#ffeeee"

set border back
plot for [LT=101:108] 'silver.dat' using 1:2 with point lt LT notitle
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Please clarify what exactly what properties your plot needs to have.

(1) The term "bubble plot" usually refers to a plot in which each point is drawn as a circle with additional properties encoded by changing the size, color, or other property of the circle. Gnuplot can do that quite well.  A good example can be found in the online demo collection: [Hypertext bubble chart](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_canvas_5.2/hypertext.html) In this case the size of the circle is used to indicate relative population and additional information is encoded as hypertext (pop-up text box) attached to that point.  Variable color could easily be added as well. The png version below does not include the hypertext.

[image]

(2) The example you link in the query does not appear to encode any additional information into the shape or color of the point but it does use a fancy glyph for each point rather than a simple dot or cross.  Gnuplot can do that also. It depends on exactly what set of symbols or glyphs you want to use.  If you can find a font providing appropriate glyphs then one way is shown here:

```
shape(i) = (i%4 == 0) ? "⊕" : (i%4 == 1) ? "⊙" : (i%4 == 2) ? "⊚" : "⦾" 
set grid x y z vertical
splot 'silver.dat' using 1:2:3:(shape(int(column(0))) with labels textcolor "forest-green"
```

[image]

More complicated options are also possible but may depend on exactly what you need and what output format (gnuplot "terminal type") is acceptable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What format supports the hypertext? I aked how to combine 3D plot (splot) and 2D plot (plot). I would like to use a 3D points that are in link in my question and 2D points.

Comment: hypertext is supported for wxt qt canvas win and svg terminal output.  I do not understand what you mean by "combine 2D plot and 3D splot".  These are two different commands; you must choose one or the other.

Comment: Ok, thank you. This is what I want to know. So, now when I want to plot graph with 3D points from file, how to do that? I look at the web page http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/09/bubble-graphs-in-gnuplot-once-more.html  and I replaced bubble.dat with my file.dat and the result was the same graf like they have in web page.

Comment: Assuming that your 3D points in the file have their x, y, and z coordinates in columns 1, 2, and 3, then you simply replace each 2D command `plot 'bubble.dat' using 1:2 with points ps 3 pt 7 lc somecolor` by the equivalent 3D command `splot 'bubble.dat' using 1:2:3 with points ps 3 pt 7 lc somecolor`

Comment: I ment not points 3D but 2D data in design of 3D spheres like points in links.

Comment: Your second link shows exactly how to do this.  See answer below.

Comment: When I use it, there weren't my data